# Compute $\int_Rx^2+y^2$, where $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|\leq|y|\leq2\}$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

> Compute the integral of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ over $R$, where $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|\leq|y|\leq2\}$.

Writing the region as $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:-2\leq y\leq2, -y\leq x\leq y\}$, we have that:

$$\int_Rx^2+y^2=\int_{-2}^2\int_{-y}^yx^2+y^2dxdy=0$$

If we think that $R$ can be divided into two pieces $R_1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:-2\leq y\leq x\leq0\}$ and $R_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:0\leq x\leq y\leq2\}$, then $\int_{R_1}f=-\int_{R_2}f$, and therefore $\int_Rf=0$.

Is my answer right? Am I making any wrong assumption? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where on earth did that minus sign come from?

Comment: Oops don't know why did I though that... So $\int_{R1}f=\int_{R2}f$ and then $\int_Rf=2\int_{R1}f=64/3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry in $x$ and $y$ the integral is the same as that over $R'$ defined
by $|y|\le|x|\le2$. Adding the two integrals gives
$$\int_{-2}^2\int_{-2}^2(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy$$
and your integral is a half of that.

Answer (score 1):

I  view of the symmetry of the integrand in $x$ and $y$ the integral is $4\int_W (x^{2}+y^{2}) d(x,y)$ where $W=\{(x,y): =0\leq x \leq y \leq 2\}$. You can  write this as $\int_0^{2}\int_x^{2}(x^{2}+y^{2}) dydx=\frac {64} 3$.